Webm audio blob to Wav file Js
i'm trying to convert a webm blob to a wav audio file.
The webm file : no problem to get it from a recorder audio stream
const url = URL.createObjectURL(recording);
const anchor = document.createElement("a");
var filename="audio.webm";
anchor.download =filename;
anchor.href = url;
anchor.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

I think it's about the stereo channel of the buffer...
I tried this but it does not work :
const arrayBuffer = await new Response(recording).arrayBuffer();
const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: "audio/wav" });

I can't use npm package...
Thanks for your help.

Where are you trying to convert the audio? There is no such conversion routine...   Changing the mime type without convert it cannot work

Hmm, what variable type is 'recording'? Is it another Blob or something else?
